# JavaScript close/hide video when clicking on another `<video>`

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

My problem is when I display `<video>` by clicking on the first button and click on another button without toggling the first button, the two videos are displaying together, how i solve it?

When I click to another button, I want the first button to be closed and hidden automatically.

JavaScript code:

```
<script> 
  function display(id) {
    var vid = document.getElementById(id);
    if (vid.style.display == 'block') {
      vid.style.display = 'none';
      vid.pause();
    } else {
      vid.style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
</script>
```

HTML code:

```
<section class="vid">
  <h3>Double click on the buttons to display the videos:</h3>
  <div><a onclick="display('ch1');"><span>Video tutorual Ch1</span></a></div>
  <div><a onclick="display('ch2');"><span>Video tutorial Ch2</span></a></div>
  <div><a onclick="display('ch3');"><span>Video tutorial Ch3</span></a></div>
  <div><a onclick="display('ch4');"><span>Video tutorial Ch4</span></a></div>
  <div><a onclick="display('ch5');"><span>Video tutorial Ch5</span></a></div>
  <div><a onclick="display('ch6');"><span>Video tutorial Ch6</span></a></div>
</section>
<video controls="" height="600px" id="ch1" src="V.mp4" width="940px"></video> 
<video controls="" height="600px" id="ch2" src="V.mp4" width="940px"></video> 
<video controls="" height="600px" id="ch3" src="V.mp4" width="940px"></video> 
<video controls="" height="600px" id="ch4" src="V.mp4" width="940px"></video> 
<video controls="" height="600px" id="ch5" src="V.mp4" width="940px"></video> 
<video controls="" height="600px" id="ch6" src="V.mp4" width="940px"></video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your click function, you need to first stop all the videos, then show and play the one video which is selected by the user via click function parameter. 
Sample code is below, can help to enhance further. You can call the `hideAndStopAll()` method to stop and hide them all while the page is loaded.

```js
   function display(id) {
            hideAndStopAll()
            var vid = document.getElementById(id);
            vid.style.display = 'block';
            vid.play();
           
         }

         var ids= ['ch1','ch2','ch3','ch4','ch5','ch6']

         function hideAndStopAll(){

             for(i=0;i<ids.length;i++){
                 var video = document.getElementById(ids[i]);
                 video.pause();
                 video.style.display='none'
             }

         }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div> <a onclick="display('ch1');"> <span>Video tutorual Ch1</span> </a> </div> 
    <div> <a onclick="display('ch2');"> <span>Video tutorial Ch2</span> </a> </div>
    <div> <a onclick="display('ch3');"> <span>Video tutorial Ch3</span> </a> </div>
    <div> <a onclick="display('ch4');"> <span>Video tutorial Ch4</span> </a> </div>
    <div> <a onclick="display('ch5');"> <span>Video tutorial Ch5</span> </a> </div>
    <div> <a onclick="display('ch6');"> <span>Video tutorial Ch6</span> </a> </div>


    <video id="ch1"   src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" controls  width="940px" height="600px"> </video>
<video id="ch2"   src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" controls  width="940px" height="600px"> </video>
<video id="ch3"   src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" controls  width="940px" height="600px"> </video>
<video id="ch4"   src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" controls  width="940px" height="600px"> </video>
<video id="ch5"   src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" controls  width="940px" height="600px"> </video>
<video id="ch6"   src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" controls  width="940px" height="600px"> </video>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Let me know if this answers your question, I am always open to improvise this.